# Loop print two list outputs into two rows

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

I have two outputs which are lists:

```
Toprow = ['Value' , '+/-' , '%+/-' , 'High' , 'Low' , 'Prev' , 'Close']
Bottomrow = ['7,424.96', '+9.01', '+0.12', '7,447.00', '7,402.64', '7,415.95']
```

I want to output them so they look something like this:

```
FTSE 100 SUMMARY
Value         +/-       %+/-     High        Low       Prev Close
7,424.96     +9.01     +0.12   7,447.00    7,402.64     7,415.95
```

I believe it would be string formatting, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make it work for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following snippet:

```
Toprow = ['Value' , '+/-' , '%+/-' , 'High' , 'Low' , 'Prev' , 'Close']
Bottomrow = ['7,424.96', '+9.01', '+0.12', '7,447.00', '7,402.64', '7,415.95']

for item in Toprow:
    print(item, (12 - len(item)) * ' ', end='')
print()
for item in Bottomrow:
    print(item, (12 - len(item)) * ' ', end='')
```

This prints out each item of `Toprow` separately, with some spaces to format it, based on the length of the item. The same happens for `Bottomrow`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a string formatting way of doing this as mentioned by [leovp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6223515/leovp).
Alternatively, there are packages that can help with better formatting; [example](https://oneau.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/simple-formatted-tables-in-python-with-texttable/) and the [link to the package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable) used in that example.